# How to return derived type while operating over base and derived class?

Tags: c++

I have two classes, `my_matrix` and `my_vector` classes, where `my_vector` derives from `my_matrix`.

When I do `my_matrix tmp = vec * mat`, it returns a matrix (`mat` is an instance of `my_matrix` and `vec` is an instance of `my_vector`).  I am fine here.

But when I do `my_vector tmp = mat * vec`, I get this error in clang++:

> no viable conversion from '`my_matrix`' to '`my_vector`'

and this error in g++:

> conversion from '`my_matrix`' to non-scalar type '`my_vector`' requested

I think I know what the problem is.  After `mat` and `vec` are multiplied, the return type is `my_matrix` and *you can't cast base class to derived class*.

What do you think the solution for this would be?

I have tried defining `void operator*(my_vector&, my_matrix&)` (not a member function of the derived class) which calls `my_vector operator*(my_matrix&)`  in the derived class, but it does not work so far.

```
class my_matrix{
public:
    my_matrix operator*(my_matrix& other_mat){
        my_matrix tmp(row, other_mat.col);
        // for loop to matrix multiply that fill up the tmp
        return tmp;
    }
};

class my_vector:public my_matrix{
public:
    // not sure if I need operator* here 
    // Somehow I want to bring the my_vector tmp = mat * vec;  here so 
    // it would return vector instead of matrix
    // I have tried : but not successful 
    // my_vector operator*(my_matrix&)
    // void operator*(my_vector&, my_matrix&); (non member)
};

int main(){
    my_matrix mat = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}; // 2x3
    my_vector vec = {1,2,3}; // 3x1

    my_vector tmp = mat * vec; // 2x3 * 3*1 gives 2x1 vector
}
```

Comment: please include the `.cpp` files, and `Matrix operator*(Matrix&)` especially, so we will have a clear picture of what is going on.

Comment: @yd1 Thank you for the reply . I have updated the question

Comment: try making the operator outside the class, and give it both of the matrices.

Comment: @yd1 you mean `my_vector operator*(Matrix&, Matrix&);` as non-member funtion in `my_vector.hpp` ?

Comment: why? you want to return a matrix: `my_matrix operator*(my_matrix& mat1, my_matrix& mat2);`

Comment: @yd1 no I actually want to return a vector

Comment: but not every matrix multiply result in 1 dimensional vector. what would you do if there is 3x4 * 4x3 matrices? (result must be 3x3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class my_matrix {
public:
    my_matrix operator*(const my_matrix& other_mat) const {
        my_matrix tmp(row, other_mat.col);
        // for loop to matrix multiply that fill up the tmp
        return tmp;
    }
};

class my_vector : public my_matrix {
public:
    using my_matrix::operator*;

    my_vector operator*(const my_vector& other_vec) const {
        my_vector tmp(...);
        // for loop to vector multiply that fill up the tmp
        return tmp;
    }
};

my_vector operator*(const my_matrix &lhs, const my_vector &rhs)
{
    my_vector tmp(...);
    // for loop to vector multiply that fill up the tmp
    return tmp;
}

int main() {
    my_matrix mat = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}; // 2x3
    my_vector vec = {1,2,3}; // 3x1

    my_vector tmp = mat * vec; // 2x3 * 3x1 gives 2x1 vector
}
```

Comment: @pokche: Like any overloaded function, an overloaded operator is resolved by the types of parameters passed in to it.  Overloads are never resolved by return type. So you can't have the same `mat * vec` expression return different types based solely on the type of variable that the result is being assigned to.  you need to decide whether `mat * vec` always return a matrix or a vector, and stick with it.

Comment: Oh! thank you .. one last thing is when is do ` return  rhs*lhs ` I am getting could not convert `my_vector::operator*(const my_matrix&) const ((* & lhs))' from 'my_matrix' to  'my_vector' .. I am currently debugging this problem will let you know when I ma done

Comment: * sorry I removed my last comment I thought about it and was not longer necessary .. I will bring it back so your answer don't sound absurd for others

Comment: Inside of `my_vector operator*(const my_matrix &lhs, const my_vector &rhs)`, a `return rhs * lhs;` statement would call `my_vector my_vector::operator*(const my_matrix &lhs)`. Oh wait, that won't work because `my_vector` does not have such an operator defined!  The inherited operators that take a matrix as input return a matrix as output, not a vector. So you would have to define an operator in the vector class that takes a matrix as input and returns a vector as output.  Or, at least define a copy constructor in the vector class that takes a matrix as input.

Comment: oh! ok I will do that and what about the rhs ? how will rhs come into play here?

Comment: What I was planing was I just do my_vector operator*(const my_matrix &lhs, const my_vector &rhs) {// do multiplication inside here instead of calling other function from here } .. and also remove my_vector's operator*  (member function)

Comment: Ok your last answer after edit makes more sense I will do accordingly

Comment: I would suggest having `my_matrix` define member operators that only operate on `my_matrix` values, `my_vector` define member operators that only operate on `my_vector` values, and then define non-member operators for mixed matrix/vector operations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126874/discussion-between-pokche-and-remy-lebeau).

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the existing `operator*`'s parameter is wrong:

```
my_matrix operator*(my_matrix& other_mat){
```

The parameter to the `*` operator should be `const`, and the method should be `const` itself. After all, the multiplication operator should not be modifying either of the operands:

```
my_matrix operator*(const my_matrix& other_mat) const {
```

With that problem out of the way, you can now meaningfully overload the operator:

```
my_vector operator*(const my_vector& other_mat) const {
```

And implement the multiplication operation in whatever way you want to define this operation to work.

Now, multiplication by a `my_matrix` returns in a `my_matrix`, and multiplication by a `my_vector` returns a `my_vector`. Your `my_matrix` overloads the `*` operator, and the return value becomes dependent on what you're multiplying it by.

Comment: When I do `my_vector operator*(const my_vector& other_vec) const{ ` it gives the same error :/

Comment: "*Your `my_matrix` overloads the `*` operator, and the return value becomes dependent on what you're multiplying it by*" - why would multiplying a matrix by a vector return a vector? Isn't the result still a matrix? When implementing a member unary operator, the return value should be the same type as the class that is defining it.  When implementing a standalone binary operator, the return value should be the left-hand type, but can be the right-hand type if that makes more sense.

Comment: As far as whether this makes sense, this is what was asked: "... when I do my_vector tmp = mat * vec" was the question, so this would be my answer. Whether that makes sense, or not, well, that would seem to be a different question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: yes, that is what the OP said, but is that the right thing it should be doing mathematically?

Comment: In that case, adding `using my_matrix::operator*` should fix that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: nevermind, I didn't notice that `my_vector` derives from `my_matrix`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but I read some here that base class should not be aware about the derived class .. and said it was bad design